# Joint Distribution with Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

[image]

I am able to understand all the math after the 2nd step of the problem, I just don't understand where they got the 4 from in the second step of the problem. I know they are using Bayes formula, but am not sure where the 4 comes from in step 2.

Comment: I think if you use the same integral for $P(Y \leq \frac{X}{2})$ as $P(Y \leq \frac{X}{4})$ it works out that $P(Y \leq \frac{X}{2}) = \frac{1}{4}$. Then we have that $\frac{P(Y \leq \frac{X}{4}, Y \leq \frac{X}{2})}{P(Y \leq \frac{X}{2})} =  \frac{P(Y \leq \frac{X}{4})}{\frac{1}{4}} = 4 P ( Y \leq \frac{X}{4})$

Comment: @RichoKicked800goals Exactly that, for all $n\geqslant 1$ $$\int_0^1 \int_0^{x/n} 10 x^2 y~\mathsf d y~\mathsf d x = \frac 1{n^2}$$

Comment: that's a nice little integral :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$P(Y \leq \frac{X}{4}) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{x}{4}} 10x^2 y \, \, dy \, \, dx $$
So then $$P(Y \leq \frac{X}{2}) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{x}{2}} 10x^2 y \, \, dy \, \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{5}{4}x^4 \,\, dx = \frac{1}{4}$$
And for the step you are confused about:
$$\frac{P(Y \leq \frac{X}{4}, Y \leq \frac{X}{2})}{P(Y \leq \frac{X}{2})} =  \frac{P(Y \leq \frac{X}{4})}{\frac{1}{4}} = 4 P ( Y \leq \frac{X}{4})$$
with $P(Y \leq \frac{X}{4}, Y \leq \frac{X}{2}) = P(Y \leq \frac{X}{4})$ as $Y$ being less than $\frac{X}{4}$  implies adding on the constraint of also being less than $\frac{X}{2}$ does not change the probability for $0 \leq X \leq 1$.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.